# How to display a good looking dotted border in table?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with CSS for a couple of hours in order to make a perfect spaced dotted line for my table. I've tried the border property, creating a image and put it as background, repeating it in Y axis, and some other stuff (even in CSS3), but my case is a little more specific than the ones I found out by searching in Google: I have alternated columns and rows classes in my table, and it seems that I can't define the whole row with a continuous border.

My CSS:

```
th { height: 42px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; vertical-align:bottom; padding: 8px 16px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-bottom: 2px dotted #999; }
th.odd { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
th.even { background-color: #ddd; }
td { padding: 16px; }
tr{ border-bottom: 2px dotted #999; }
tr.even { background-color: #eee; }
tr.even td.even { background-color: #e2e2e2; }
tr.odd td.even { background-color: #eaeaea; }
```

I've tried also to change the "border-bottom" ones to a background-image with dots and spaces, as I mentioned before.

What I have today is this:

[image]

And I want the the dots to be continuous as this: . . . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: You can see the dots join together at the meeting point of the <td>s, he wants them not to join, but be evenly spaced for the whole width of the row.

Comment: Can you make your code into a jsfiddle?

Comment: @AndrewB or an SO snippet? Its the document icon with the `<>` in it and it's native. Also, I don't think this one is possible.

Comment: Is the content of your table actually tabular information, or are you just using a table to format it? if it is the latter, use divs. You should be able to get a continuous border on a div.

Comment: This is sort of achievable with gradients as background images but I am not sure if you really want to do something that complex for what I'd call a minor problem. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/tsrd6osr/) is a very rough sample of what can be achieved.

Comment: @AndrewB, please, check my explanation for the table usage in Pavel's solution, right below. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Disclaimer: This is not a simple solution and is rather complex to understand but if you really want to produce continuous dots then this is the only approach that I can think of. I wouldn't recommend adding so much complexity for what is a small aberration with the borders but I'd leave it to you.

The approach for creating the continuous border is:

- A dotted background is added to the `table` itself using `radial-gradient` images. Since `table` is the parent container, the dots stretch continuously in a seamless manner.
- The size of the background gradient in Y-axis is equivalent to height of the `td` + the `padding` on either side. This is critical to the working.
- The position of the background in Y-axis is calculated as -1 * (background-size in Y-axis/2) - 2px.
- The `background-repeat` is set to `round` so that it kind of always produces full dots. All these are critical to the solution.
- Colors cannot be added to the `td` or the `tr` as solid colors because they would hide the `table` background and so the solution is to add them via `linear-gradient` (except that the color does not change). This is done because the size of gradients can be controlled whereas that of solid color cannot be.

```css
table { /* to produce the dots via radial gradient */
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, black 1px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 8px 50px; /* size in y-axis is equal to td height + padding top + padding bottom */
  background-position: 2px -27px; /* position in y-axis is -1 * size/2 - 2px */
  background-repeat: round; /* makes dots repeat in round manner */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 46px; 
  padding: 2px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee, #eee);
  background-size: 100% 46px; /* size in y-axis is height of td */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e2e2e2, #e2e2e2);
  background-size: 100% 46px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #eaeaea);
  background-size: 100% 46px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World!!!</td>
    <td>Hello World!!!</td>
    <td>Hello World!!!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi There!!!</td>
    <td>Hi There!!!</td>
    <td>Hi There!!!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

As shown in the fiddle that you had provided in comments, the whole thing becomes a lot simpler if all the `td` will have some solid color as their background (either white or other shades of gray). In such cases, we don't need the extra `linear-gradient` backgrounds for the `td` or the other `background-*` properties. This approach would work even when the dimensions of the `tr` and `td` are not fixed.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, #999 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 4px 2px;
  background-repeat: round;
}
td {
  padding: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
tr.odd td.odd {
  background: #fff padding-box;  /* the padding-box property is to prevent the background from being present under the 2px transparent border area */
}
tr.even td.odd {
  background: #eee padding-box;
}
tr.even td.even {
  background: #e2e2e2 padding-box;
}
tr.odd td.even {
  background: #eaeaea padding-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td class="even">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum
      <br>Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum
      <br>Dolor
      <br>Sit
      <br>Amet</td>
    <td class="even">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td class="even">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td class="odd">Lorem
      <br>Ipsum
      <br>Dolor
      <br>Sit
      <br>Amet</td>
    <td class="even">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td class="odd">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll try your solution. Wait for further feedback! =)

Comment: Sorry, Harry. I accidentally replied in your answer the reply I would give for Mosh. That's why I edited my answer above. I'm trying yours now!

Comment: Ok, already tested. Worked like a charm, UNTIL I put some big text inside one of the columns. There was a line break, and the dots were transformed into vertical bars. The problem lies in row's height. But then, I've put the background-size as 100% (X and Y) and inserted the following css: `td { border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;}`, and it has solved the dynamic height issue! So, I'll choose your answer as the right one, but if you could edit it to work as I mentioned here it would be great. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @thiagoprzy: I tried applying those settings and it doesn't quite work out. I am having to set `background-size: 100% calc(100% - 4px)` for it to work. Maybe you have some extra settings in your code which is helping. Can you give me a link to your code so that I can edit the answer accordingly?

Comment: @thiagoprzy: Sorry, I seem to have missed your comment. I can understand why 100% works in your code. I always assumed that the non-colored `td` were transparent but in your code they are all either white or different shades of gray. This means that the background of the body (the radial gradients) show through the transparent area of the `border-botom`. In such cases we don't even need the `background-size` or `linear-gradient` for `td`. A simple solid background color itself would work like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4wwa47h4/1/).

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `border-left : 1px solid white` to separate double dots. But create the table using `<div>`. For this, it is the better way.

```css
.row {
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
}
.columnG {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.columnW {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnG">
    XXXX
  </div>
  <div class="columnW">
    XXXX
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnG">
    XXXX
  </div>
  <div class="columnW">
    XXXX
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the border-left, but it doesn't split the dots, unfortunately. I'm drawing a "css-pattern" for a company, and they want this to be a table (I'm not responsible for the HTML). They sent me a PDF with the way the components should look like, and this dotted border is a must-have (although I think it's a really minor issue). Vote up for the div solution.

Comment: It is true. With a design built around < div > can do more tricks easily.

Answer (score 3):

Is the demo I'm using `radial gradient` to make the dots. You can "play" with the `range` control at the bottom do find the exact result.

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  $('tr').css('background-size', $(this).val() + 'px 4px'); 
  $('#num').html($(this).val());
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
tr {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, black 1px, transparent 1.5px) repeat-x bottom;
  background-size: 5px 4px;  
}
tr:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  /*border-bottom:1px dotted #aaa;*/
  /*background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, black 1px, transparent 1.5px) repeat-x bottom;
  background-size: 5px 4px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input type="range" value="5" min="5" max="15" />
<pre>background-size: <span id="num">5</span>px 4px;</pre>
```

Comment: Who `still merge`? The dots in the border?

Comment: Yes exactly, your result matches what he already has, instead of what he wants.

Comment: @AndrewB I just was updated my code. This code using `radial gradient` but not `border`.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick pal but as long as we keep setting the `border` or `background` to the `td` it won't be fully continuous because the width of the `td` would then have to be exact multiples of `background-size` and this isn't always possible. For example, check with `background-size: 8px 4px;`.

Comment: @Harry OK. You are right. I just was updated the code so the `tr` will accept the background `radial gradient`.

Comment: @MoshFeu: I have a feeling that any further comment might look like I am promoting my answer over yours (which is not my aim) but it still seems to have a problem for `background-size: 12px 4px;` (not sure why it happens because you have already set it on `tr`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is an interesting solution, but I had the same issue after configuring this the way I wanted - the dots are not being continuous (not "glued" to each other, but with different spacing). The solution could be a dynamic padding, but it's complicated to predict how much padding is needed for each column, since it depends on the table content. I believe I'll need to go to a javascript solution =(

Answer (score 1):

Using a pseudo element on the table row worked well for me.

```
tr {
  position: relative;
}

 tr::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a tr > td > div approach to get a nice looking dashed border. If you put the dashed border on either the td or tr, the dashes run into each other depending on the length of the td which creates a weird looking effect where the dashes are longer than they should be.

```
const RowBorder = styled('div')`
  border-top: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
`;
return (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colSpan="6">
          <RowBorder />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
        <td>Col4</td>
        <td colSpan="2">Col5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colSpan="6">
          <RowBorder />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
  </table>
)
```